# Vim: . (period) repeats the last command. What is the command to repeat the last but one commands?

Tags: vim

Vim: `.` repeats the last command. What's the command to repeat the last but one command?

Ex:

I deleted a line using the command `dd`, and then I deleted a character using the command `x`.

`x` is the last command and `dd` is the last but one command.

The last command `x` can be repeated using `.`
But, I want to repeat `dd` using something like `.`.

Comment: make an example pls.

Comment: @Kent: Example given

Comment: You know about [vi.stackexchange.com](http://vi.stackexchange.com)? (I would love to answer your question instead of giving you a link, but I know of no such feature.)

Comment: @DevSolar: I didn't know about that site. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: there's no such feature native to Vim.

However, the following suggestions should help you get more out of Vim:

- For your **specific example**, instead of typing `dd` to delete the line you could use the `:d` Ex (command-line) delete command. This can be later repeated using `@:` without effecting the `.` command.
- If you're doing **something more complicated than deleting a line** with `dd`, you could record it as a macro using `q{registername}` (where `{registername}` denotes any unused non-special register name in the range `a`-`z`, e.g., `qa`). After having executed the macro using `@{registername}` (e.g., `@a`) it can be repeated by simply running `@@`.
- If you'd like to learn more about **other ways of repeating commands**, I'd suggest reading `repeat.txt` from Vim's built-in manual:

  ```
  :h repeat.txt
  ```

  This file lists other ways of repeating commands such as using Ex commands and recording / executing macros.

#### Repeating substitution commands

The most recent `:substitute` command can be repeated using `:s` or `:&`. This uses the same search pattern and substitution string but not the same flags or range (they have to be provided). An even shorter synonym for this *repeat* command is `&`. See `:help :substitute` for more information.

Comment: @SagarJain Correct. I intended `{registername}` to denote any valid register name from `a` to `z`. I'll edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: @SagarJain I edited my answer to add an extra section on repeating substitution commands.